# Inserting data into 2-D Python Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I currently have a script that takes US weather data and displays it using Basemap. Unfortunately I can't get it to run successfully unless I have a full lat/lon (180,360) array (US data is size (31,61)). Is it possible to make an array the size of (180,360), and then insert my US data in that array where it should exist?

I've tried the following, and was unsuccessful:

```
full_latlon = np.insert(latlon, latlon[20:50,240:300], US_data)
```

I got the following error, but I'm not sure what it means: ValueError: index array argument obj to insert must be one dimensional or scalar.

I tried finding similar problems on stackoverflow, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that full_latlon.shape == (180, 360) and US latitudes and longitudes start at 20 and 240 respectively:

```
full_latlon[20:51, 240:301] = US_data
```

Comment: Never thought of it this way! I was stuck on using np.insert that I didn't think of array slicing. Thank you!